# docker php function not impelemnted

Tags: php, docker

```
fwrite("[2020-02-24 20:02:45] local.ERROR: fwrite(): write of 4666 bytes failed with errno=38 Function not implemented
```

Весь интернет перерыл, не могу понять в чем дело. Когда на php пытаюсь сохранить файл, удалить, или перенести, все падает. Хз что пошло не так, кто нибудь может сталкивался?

Comment: Такое ощущение, что у вас какая-то неправильная версия php. Обновлять не пробовали на более новую/старую ?

Comment: @ArchDemon разобрался что такое, короче докер потерял связь с диском где маунтился, перезапуск не помогал, но когда снес его весь и заново поставил - все просто заработало